# Magento taking 20 seconds to load

Tags: magento2, varnish, pagespeed, speedoptimization, loading

I have recently migrated our Magento 2 store to a new Instance in `AWS` after setting up Magento store in new instance the store loading time is increased to `22 seconds` before In previous instance It was 12 seconds.
Some time It keeps on loading and displays `503 Gateway time out`
Kindly help !!

After migration my menu was not displayed so I removed

```
TTL="330" Frm default.xml file of `Magento_theme`
```

The varnish from the Magento admin is configured but not at the server `default.vcl` FILE

Full page cache is enabled and store is in production mode , Kindly help with solution

Comment: Could you please send me the URL of the website if possible?

Comment: If not then, try to set up this in your local, disable third-party extensions, theme if require and see it is loading fast or not. Or else please check log and try to fix issue.

Comment: Here's a step-through kind of [checklist for Magento 2 performance](https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/magento-2-performance-checklist).

Comment: It could be the case you chose an instance which can't fully adapt your M2 store performance requirement.

Comment: 2 CPU and 4 GN ram